# jenkins behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I've added [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx) `.conf` content in my `nginx_jenkins.conf` inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d` (changing `server_name` variable).

After that, when I get access to jenkins, it warns me something is wrong with my reverse-proxy (nginx).

However after having added this nginx configuration, jenkins keeps the message.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've just updated jenkins to 2.14. The warning remains.